# Sending request to FCM using Typhoeus::Request in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to send a simple request to FCM using Typhoeus::Request. It seems I'm doing something terribly wrong but can't come up with any clues since a few hours...

This is how I send request to FCM:

```
req = Typhoeus::Request.new(
        Fcm_server_uri,
        method: :post,
        params: {:to => fcm_registration_id},
        headers: {'Authorization' => Fcm_server_api_key,'Content-Type' => "application/json",charset: "UTF-8"})

    req.run
    response = req.response

    body = response.body
```

I keep getting following message in the response.body:

```
"JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0."
```

The error message says clearly that sth with Json might be wrong and I tried already various combinations of supplying my Json and no success yet. I would be really grateful for any tips!

Comment: Can you try adding `'key='` before your `Fcm_server_api_key`? Usually for the value of `Authorization` the value passed is formatted as `key=<server_key_here>`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately I had already tried both cases: with the "key=server_key" and without the "key=". Without it the server returns wrong authentication key so I eneded up using "key=server_key"

Answer (score 1):

I'm totally confused as to why sending Jsons to FCM doesn't work in Typhoeus but I finally managed to send successful request by changing Content-Type from application/json to plain text and sending my message in plain text format of course.

Here's complete helper module I wrote for convenience:

```
module FcmModule
  require 'typhoeus'
  require 'typhoeus/request'

  Fcm_server_api_key = 'key=<YOUR_SERVER_KEY>'
  Fcm_server_uri = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'

  Status_message_sent = 0
  Status_failed = 1
  Status_not_registered = 2
  Status_update_registration_id = 3

  def send_notification_to_fcm(title, description, from_teacher,
                               notification_type_id, fcm_registration_id)

    req = Typhoeus::Request.new(
        Fcm_server_uri,
        method: :post,
        body: "registration_id=#{fcm_registration_id}&" +
            "data.myFromTeacher=#{from_teacher}&" +
            "data.myTitle=#{title}&" +
            "data.myDescription=#{description}&" +
            "data.myNotificationTypeId=#{notification_type_id}",

        headers: {'Authorization' => Fcm_server_api_key,'Content-Type' => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",charset: "UTF-8"})

    req.run
    response = req.response

    body = response.body
    bodyResults = Hash[body.each_line.map { |l| l.chomp.split('=', 2) }]

    if !bodyResults['id'].nil? && !bodyResults['registration_id'].nil?
      return FcmResponse.new(bodyResults['id'], bodyResults['registration_id'], Status_update_registration_id)
    end

    if !bodyResults['Error'].nil?
      if bodyResults['Error'] == 'NotRegistered'
        return FcmResponse.new(nil, nil, Status_not_registered)
      else
        return FcmResponse.new(nil, nil, Status_failed)
      end
    else
      return FcmResponse.new(bodyResults['id'], nil, Status_message_sent)
    end

  end

  class FcmResponse

    def initialize(message_id, registration_id, status)
      @message_id = message_id
      @registration_id = registration_id
      @status = status
    end

    def message_id
      @message_id
    end

    def registration_id
      @registration_id
    end

    def status
      @status
    end

  end
end
```

Here's an example of using the module:

```
fcm_response = send_notification_to_fcm('title','description', 'from_teacher', 1, fcm_registration_id)
        if fcm_response.status == Status_message_sent
          # todo save to our users notifications in database
        elsif fcm_response.status == Status_update_registration_id
          # todo update fcm_registration_id for given device with fcm_response.registration_id
        elsif fcm_response.status == Status_not_registered
          # todo delete given device from our database
        elsif fcm_response.status == Status_failed
          # todo return some error message to client to retry sending the notification
        end
```

EDIT:

Ekhm, well I couldn't let it go and looked at the code once more. In order to send a Json in post Typhoeus Request I had to provide the hash in "body" parameter, NOT "params". Here's working request for sending Json:

```
req = Typhoeus::Request.new(
        Fcm_server_uri,
        method: :post,
        body: {'to' => fcm_registration_id}, # body instead of params!
        headers: {'Authorization' => Fcm_server_api_key,'Content-Type' => "application/json",charset: "UTF-8"})

    req.run
    response = req.response

    body = response.body
```

Now excuse me, I need to bang my head against a wall...